# ASP.NET MVC Usage of User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

So this is more of a 'Can I use it like that' question and 'Is it good practice or maybe I should do it different'. I'm specifically interested in Users. 
Let's say my app has a model called Tasks and each task has properties like this:

```
public class Task
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public int? UserID { get; set; }  //Who's assigned to this Task
}
```

Is it okay to state users like this and the in controller get drop down list of them like this:

```
@using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
  @Html.DropDownList("UserID", new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "UserName"))        
}
```

(Basically when creating a task I'd assign a User to it).
Is it good practice? Maybe there are other better ways to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should not use `dbcontext` instance in your `cshtml` page, You should do it either in controller,

You can assign users list to the viewbag in controller like

```
 var db = new ApplicationDbContext()
 ViewBag.Users = new SelectList(db.Users.ToList(),  "Id", "UserName");
```

and in cshtml you should bind like ,

```
@Html.DropDownList("User", ViewBag.Users)
```

Comment: why is that bad and why is this good? (I want to understand in depth)

Comment: @HighSepton accordingly design it is bad practice, you are tightly coupling your view with your business entities, actually you should pass viewmodel to the view, not actual business entity(i.e. Task)

Comment: okay, other than that is having User like that in the model alright or maybe it could be better?

Comment: @HighSepton your model of Task is alright it can have User and proper designed, but how you are binding with view is bad practice,

Comment: I kind of made up that on the spot, because my main thought was about the Model. I would do it with a ViewModel firstly and secondly I would do it like you suggested probably. Maybe I'd return a IEnumerable rather than a ViewBag

Comment: @programtreasures, Its better than your code because at least it will not throw an error - you need to cast it if your using terrible practice like `ViewBag` :)

Comment: can we continue this in chat? @StephenMuecke

Comment: @HighSepton. Use our [previous room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166236/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-highsepton)